# What is docker-entrypoint.sh in docker ps

Tags: docker, docker-compose

when I execute `docker ps` following was returned

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                NAMES
285a40d8fe9c   busybox                        "top"                    10 hours ago   Up 10 hours                                                                        affectionate_nightingale
93eccc49d12e   localstack/localstack:0.14.0   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   12 hours ago   Up 12 hours   4510-4559/tcp, 5678/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4566->4566/tcp, :::4566->4566/tcp   docker_localstack_1
577c50d348d1   docker_db                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 hours ago   Up 12 hours   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3314->3306/tcp, :::3314->3306/tcp                 mysql_host
```

I wonder what is `docker-entrypoint.sh` in `CMD`. I understand that `CMD` define PID1 , in other words,it define purpose of this container and what should be done by each container.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mysql:8.0
COPY initdb.d/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

If someone know what is `docker-entrypoint.sh` will you please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Since it's a shell script, you could just look at it.   The name tells you almost nothing, since it's a name that many programmers might choose for their Docker entrypoint shell scripts.

Comment: But here's one that seems to be associated with mysql:  https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 2):

It is the image's entrypoint.

The base image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/546838ab256ad36a9f6571e900deb7c4040cd383/8.0/Dockerfile.debian#L93) declares an `ENTRYPOINT` to run that shell script.  Your derived image inherits that `ENTRYPOINT`, but replaces its `CMD`.  Since the image has both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` [these are combined into a single command and its arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and you are seeing that combined command there.

A typical use for `ENTRYPOINT` is as a wrapper that does some first-time setup, then executes the `CMD`.  The `mysql:8` image follows this pattern.  Its [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/546838ab256ad36a9f6571e900deb7c4040cd383/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) is rather involved: it takes responsibility for creating the initial database storage, starting a temporary database, running anything in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory, and then eventually calling `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`.

For the Dockerfile you show, you don't need to repeat the `CMD`; its [base image](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/546838ab256ad36a9f6571e900deb7c4040cd383/8.0/Dockerfile.debian#L96) already declares an identical `CMD` and it's fine to just inherit it.  This similarly applies to other images like `tomcat`, `php:fpm`, or `nginx` where the base image is a complete runnable thing and not just a language runtime.